# From where magento 2 set Template Id for order email

Tags: magento2, sales-order, email-templates

I know already that in Magento 1 Directory `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php` have code

```
// Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    }
```

But I don't know in Magento 2 where they set Template Id for order email.

Can anyone know From where this code executed in Magento 2?

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto the below file:

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Container/OrderIdentity.php

You will see 2 functions:

```
public function getGuestTemplateId()
{
    return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $this->getStore()->getStoreId());
}
```

and

```
public function getTemplateId()
{
    return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $this->getStore()->getStoreId());
}
```

From these it identify the templates and it defines as const at the top of the same file like below:

```
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE = 'sales_email/order/guest_template';
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'sales_email/order/template';
```

Also you can check the below file:

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php

From where it prepare the template:

```
protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
{
    $this->templateContainer->setTemplateOptions($this->getTemplateOptions());

    if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getGuestTemplateId();
        $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getTemplateId();
        $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
    }

    $this->identityContainer->setCustomerName($customerName);
    $this->identityContainer->setCustomerEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());
    $this->templateContainer->setTemplateId($templateId);
}
```

Here you can see these 2 lines:

**For Guest:**

```
$templateId = $this->identityContainer->getGuestTemplateId();
```

**For Logged in Customers:**

```
$templateId = $this->identityContainer->getTemplateId();
```

Hope this helps!